# Getting warning while recording " MP AVAudioSessionDelegateMediaPlayerOnly end interruption"

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, avassetwriter

I have been recording video successfully in my app using `AVAssetWriter` for long time but today I start to see some strange warning comes when I stop recording,

Scenario:

- I record the video & can record again the video multiple times **[NO WARNINGS]**
- I play the video in `MPMoviePlayerController` **[NO WARNINGS]**
- I record the video after playing the video and once I click stop recording I get the warning

Warning:

```
MP AVAudioSessionDelegateMediaPlayerOnly end interruption. Interruptor <RecorderServer> category <(null)> resumable <0>,  _state = 0
```

Does anyone know what might be the issue or had similar issue like I have?

Comment: can you please supply some example code, this is impossible to debug without any context for what you are actually doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It feels like I have solved my problem, although it was not a big issue just a minor mistake which I did,when I play video  in `MPMoviePlayerController` , after I finish playing video using the notification, i was not releasing the player object, I thought it would be enough to unregister from the notification but it helped when i set the `self.player=nil;`

Comment: Ok. I thought about that. Perfect !

Comment: thanks for your concern, it is nice to have some answer after many days at-least :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your audio session category is set to kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback when you play which is ok. Change it to a suitable category for recording. 
Look the different available categories here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW1